# How tension in a cable justifies the fundamental equation F = Ma?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I have read that *force* cause a body to *accelerate*. However, the cable is not accelerating.

Answer (score 1):

If a 1kg mass is hung on the end of a cable, then a 10N force acts downward on the cable. If the cable is hung from a ceiling, then a 10N force pulls the cable up. F = 10N + -10N = 0.

A better language for this is $\vec{a} = \frac{1}{m} \sum  \vec{F}$